# Wifi is slower than Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I've recently upgraded from a 10mb download speed con to 15 mb.

When i have 10 mb wifi was just fine and i was downloading over wifi at 1.1MB/s.

Now when on 15mb plan, some how my wifi speed have decreased dramatically and i only get around 400k/sec while downloading over wifi.

When connected to ethernet cable it works just fine at 1.7MB/s.

My router is Asus 604g.

How come that after upgrading my plan my wifi speed got slower?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the line from the ISP may have a fault - I suggest you try a continuous ping from your computer to an external IP like 8.8.8.8 and see how many packets are dropped.

Comment: i just did, none were lost, although time of ping did change from 85ms to ~300ms

Comment: If you want to troubleshoot this properly, you need to use a controlled download, preferably on your LAN. WiFi speed has nothing to do with equipment outside of your home/office. When you switched services, did you switch wifi equipment?

Comment: It depends on where you are in the world, but from the UK it takes ~23. It sounds like there is a fault on your line. I would also do a tracert 8.8.8.8 to see if you can see a jump on the hops at a certain point. Not very reliable but on occasions conclusive.

Comment: Or, your new service means you no longer have a prioritized line?

Comment: first it is the same ISP and the same equipment. I think it is problem at ISP side since as we are talking i tried again on wireless and now i get around 1MB on the download speed.. it changes every couple mins.. thanks guys

Comment: ah - remember most ISP's say that a new service or upgrade can take up to a week for 'the line to settle'

Comment: There is a chance it is also something environmental - like a neighbor put up a new access point on the same channel as your wifi, and it just so happened to coincide with changing ISP/services. What does your latency look like while pinging your default gateway? are they other computers on your LAN you can do a bandwidth test between as well?

Comment: Nadav, by "15mb plan" do you mean 15 MB/s or 15 Mb/s?

Answer (score 0):

Contact your ISP for this, for further investigate, If you have not made changes on your modem/router or firewall setting on router/computer, there is no reason why you wont get full speed.

Try some speed test sites, and i assume your ISP has speed test tools also, here on israel we usually check against the ISP, he tells us go to speedtest.SOMEPROVIDER.co.il and check the speed, if the speed is not as we pay, and there is nothing wrong, they bring a technical guy to check the line.

Since no changes were made in the router modem or computer, this questions can be answered by them.